# How to correct the extension specification in this file uploading script?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am making an upload script and i have coded so that no file except image would not be uploaded but the script is also uploading other files and also when i echo the extension it just displays the strpos of $name. Can anyone help???? I have saved two files, 1) uploader.php and 2) uploader2.php. The uploader.php contains form of the uploading script

```
    <h1>Upload your pictures for free</h1>
<form action="uploader2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="uploads">
<input type="submit" value="Update">
```

The uploader2.php contains the uploading script to folder uploads/

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$name = $_FILES['uploads']['name'];
echo $type= $_FILES['uploads']['type'];
$extension = strtolower($name,strpos($name,'.')+1));
$size = $_FILES['uploads']['size'];

$max_size = "20000000";
$t_n = $_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'];

if(isset($name)) {
if(!empty($name)) {

if(($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" || $extension=="bmp" || $extension=="gif")                            && ($type="image/jpeg" || $type="image/bmp")&&($size<=$max_size)){

$location="uploads/";

if(move_uploaded_file($t_n,$location.$name)){
echo "Uploaded!";
}else{
echo "An error occured";
}
}
else{
echo "The uploading file must be jpg or jpeg and should have size less than 1mb";
}
}

else {
echo "Please choose a file";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Just a note: You have an extra `(` in `if(($extension==`.

Comment: @geomagas I think there are the correct amount of `(` there.

Comment: Only images allowed: Is that all what you want to implement?

Comment: yes!! @BhavikShah... i wanted only image files like jpg, png etc will be uploaded but when i execute this script not only image file other files with different extension also gets uploaded.

Comment: @putvande Oops! I missed the gap... Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to get extension

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
```

Comment: i think, `pathinfo` is better way to get extension. Refer more details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: Why include `$allowedExts` when its not used in your example? Also what Bhavik said.